# Find the closure in $(\mathbb{R}^2, \tau)$ of the following sets.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\tau$ be the topology in $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose open sets are of the form
>   $$G_t = \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x>y+t\}$$
>   where $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Are lines closed sets of this topology? If not, which is their closure?

The open sets of this topology look like $\mathbb{R}^2$ cut with lines of the type $y=x-t$ where $t$ runs through the reals. Now, a set is closed if its complement is open, so let's take an arbitrary line in $\mathbb{R}^2$
$$y=mx+b$$
Then, the complement lf the line is
$$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y< mx +b\}\cup \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y>mx+b\}$$
so even if $m=1$, only the first set is open in $\tau$, so it doesn't look lime ines are open in $\tau$, but I lack a formal proof lr that or how should I procee.

For the other part regarding the closure of lines in $\tau$, I'd really need a hand with that. I know that the closure of a set $A$ is defined as the smallest closed set that contains $A$ but I don't know how closed sets look like in this topology so definition doesn't seem a good starting point. Thanks in advnce!

**EDIT:** Could be the closure of a line be the whole plane $\mathbb{R}^2$? If the slope $m$ is not one, and since the lines $x=y+t$ are all parallel to the line $x=y$, for any $t\in \mathbb{R}$, $x=y+t$ and $y=mx +b$ are going to intersect somewhere and hence, there will be points of the line some of then belonging to $G_t$ and some of the to its complement.Now, closed sets are of the form $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x\leq y+t\}$, so there is no set other than $\mathbb{R}^2$ containing the line $y=mx+b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You should try to find out: What is a closed set? How does it look like? (very easy if you remember that a complement of an open set is closed, and vica versa).

Hint: Then find the closure of a line (remember a closed set containing all points of the line).

Comment: Thanks! Could you check my edit? I think I followed your hints but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Comment: OK, and what about the case when the slope is one?

Comment: In that case, the set $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x\leq y+t\}$ contains the line $x=y+t$, and is closed since its complement is $G_t$. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly! As all closed sets look like this there are not many choices in your space...

Comment: Nice! So the closure is the whole if the slope is $\neq 1$ and the complement of $G_t$ if equals $1$. Thank you!

Comment: You've got it !

Comment: To @H. H. Rugh if we define the application $\Pi: \mathbb{R^2} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $\Pi(x,y)=(y-x)/2$, which projects orthogonaly points of $\mathbb{R^2}$ onto the line with equation $y=-x$, the topology given by user313212 is the coarsest on $\mathbb{R^2}$ that makes $\Pi$ continuous ($\mathbb{R}$ endowed with its usual topology)

Comment: Nice picture but the topology on ${\Bbb R}$ used here is a bit bizarre: It consists (using your map) of the open sets of the form $]-\infty,t[$ as well as ${\Bbb R}$ and the emptyset (but nothing else).